# how to pass a variable to puppeteer page.$eval();

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I declared a variable and I am trying to pass it into an `eval` but it does not get displayed. How can I properly pass a variable.

```
var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-D');
await page.$eval('#middleContent_txtEndDate', el => el.value = now);
```

If I declare a variable inside the `eval` function it works:

```
var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-D');
await page.$eval('#middleContent_txtEndDate', el => el.value = "it works");
```

Answer (score 40):

You can pass [aditional arguments](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameevalselector-pagefunction-args-1), to `$eval`

```js
const now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-D');

await page.$eval('#middleContent_txtEndDate', (el, now, foo) => {
   console.log(el, now, foo);
   return el.value = now;
}, now, 'foo');
```

Comment: God Bless You Abundantly for this

Comment: I forgot to make timout for 2s ,it worked await page.$eval('#USERNAME', (el, user) => el.value = user, USER);