# Pass the variable to nested arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have a function that contains a nested arrow function. The nested arrow function needs to access the variable `attribute` which is always `undefined`. Why is that? How can I make `e.getAttribute()` access `attribute` variable?

```
this.getAttr = async (locator, attribute) => {
        return await page.$eval(locator, e =>
                e.getAttribute(attribute)
        );
};
```

Comment: That should work perfectly well as long as `.getAttr()` is passed a value for its second parameter. Have you tried `console.log(attribute)` **before** the `return` statement to verify that it's defined?

Comment: `page.$eval` suggests you're using some web testing framework. Those will actually *serialise* your function and re-create it on the page. The serialisation process loses all closure references.

Comment: [how to pass a variable to puppeteer page.$eval();](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59899932)

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me to right direction. Here is the working code
`this.getAttr = async (locator, attribute) => {
    return await page.$eval(
      locator,
      (element, attribute) => {
        return element.getAttribute(attribute);
      },
      attribute
    );
  };
`