# Evaluation failed: ReferenceError occurs when call evaluate function

Tags: puppeteer, referenceerror, evaluate

When you call evaluate in puppeteer, an error occurs as follows.
'Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: cov_mjds8ir32 is not defined'

also 'page.$eval' occurs same error

```
page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto("https://myurl.com",{timeout: 5000, waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
await page.evaluate(() => {
     console.log("log");
});
```

---

```
const userid = 'myid';
page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto("https://myurl.com",{timeout: 5000, waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
await page.$eval('#input[name=userid]', el => el.value = userid);
```

Comment: What's `"https://myurl.com"` actually? Your code isn't a [mcve] and doesn't correspond to the `cov_mjds8ir32` error shown since that variable isn't used anywhere in your code. Otherwise, please see [how to pass a variable to puppeteer page.$eval();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899932/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-puppeteer-page-eval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Yaroslavm.
In my case, I had to do it using a template string.

The code below as an example

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
     console.log("log");
});
```

After making this change, it ran normally.

```
await page.evaluate(`(async() => {
  console.log('1');
})()`);
```

The reference link is below:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1665#issuecomment-354241717

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your selector, I guess, `input[name=userid]` and not `#input[name=userid]`.

`$eval` signature is

```js
$eval<Selector extends string, Params extends unknown[], 
Func extends EvaluateFuncWith<NodeFor<Selector>, Params> = 
EvaluateFuncWith<NodeFor<Selector>, Params>>(selector: Selector, 
pageFunction: Func | string, ...args: Params)
```

where `pageFunction` is `Function` and `...args` is params that can be passed to that function.

Function itself has it's own scope of visibility.
It's executed in `page` context and page context doesn't know anything about test context.

To make function see vars from test context, you should pass them as a function argument.

```js
await page.$eval('input[name=userid]', (el, _userId) => el.value = _userid, userId);
```