# Node require constant undefined inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I am working in Node (commonjs) and I have a `const` that I am grabbing with `require` and `module.exports` and it is coming through fine within one function but once I'm inside a function in the function, it is all of a sudden undefined.

**main.js**

```
const SRLoginCredentials = require('./secrets.js');

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');

// Add stealth plugin and use defaults
const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const { executablePath } = require('puppeteer');

// Use stealth
puppeteer.use(pluginStealth());

// Launch puppeteer-stealth
puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, executablePath: executablePath() }).then(async (browser) => {
  // Create a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Go to the website
  await page.goto('https://google.com');

  // Wait for security check
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

  await page.waitForSelector('#APjFqb');
  console.log(SRLoginCredentials);            // SRLoginCredentials is defined
  
  await page.$eval('#email', (el) => (console.log(SRLoginCredentials));            // SRLoginCredentials is undefined


  await browser.close();
});
```

**secrets.js**

```
const SRLoginCredentials = {
  email: 'my.email@gmail.com',
  password: 'some_pass',
};

module.exports = SRLoginCredentials;
```

**package.json**

```
"type": "commonjs",
```

Any insight into why that's happening would be much appreciated!

Comment: The function passed to eval is evaluated in the browser's context, so the node context isn't being captured as one would suppose. Pass what you need, like  SRLoginCredentials, as additional params to eval.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59899999/294949.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@danh answered my question perfectly in a comment above!